# Can't run filter on query results in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Lending Library management with Google Sheets.

I would like to manage a small lending library with 2 google sheets.

One would be a private sheet that lists the inventory:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XcP4mJpH0ONxqYmlq9zEeLEjP4lV75xpEGgQjhWR71M/edit?usp=sharing

The other would be a public sheet that shows only books that are available:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-isyr2r1jyPKgI0mpMg326cnLH-imQS89GggTnPKpE/edit?usp=sharing

In order to generate the list of available books, I am using
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XcP4mJpH0ONxqYmlq9zEeLEjP4lV75xpEGgQjhWR71M/edit","Sheet1!A1:H16"),"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 where Col8 is null")

I would like for someone to be able to enter their name in the public sheet request check out column and have that name reflected in the private sheet so that the book no longer shows as available.  That's the part I could use some help with.

Comment: So, you want to be able to automatically "check out" books? You are going to need to use a script for that, so I suggest you check the google script documentation. We won't be able to give you a tutorial here at SO but if after trying yo u run into issues/have questions, we should be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking there 'should' be a way to do it without a script.  However, when I try and use VLOOKUP on the QUERY results it doesn't return what I'd expect.  See column "I" in the private sheet.

Comment: What do you want exactly? if you want it to show an empty line if there is no name, you can simply add `=IFERROR(/* your function here */, "")`

Comment: Also, alway add 0 as the last argument in a VLOOKUP or you'll have surprises

Comment: @LioraHaydont, thank you, I believe your suggestions will allow me to make this work, maybe not quite the way I had in mind initially, but your tips about IFERROR and VLOOKUP were both very helpful.